# Handling duplicates with wp_insert_term()

Tags: errors, terms

I'm using `wp_insert_term` which works quite well

Now I want some error handler for when using the same name.

```
$term_id = wp_insert_term( $term, 'wpsc_product_category', $args );
if($term_id) {//my operations here}
```

where `$term = $_POST['categoryTitle'];`

I want to display some error when such name already exists.

In [wp_insert_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term), how to check if this `$term_id` is duplicate?
I don't want to continue my operations on already existing terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( is_wp_error($term_id) ) {

  // oops WP_Error obj returned, so the term existed prior
  // echo $term_id->get_error_message();
}
```

See if that works for you.